# Join is not a function

Tags: javascript, peg, pegjs

I'm playing around with [PEG.js](http://pegjs.org/online)

```
start = keyword

keyword = a:[a-z]? {return a.join("");}
```

Why am I getting here the error:

> a.join is not a function

when I enter a valid string like `abc`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`join()` is an array-function, you cannot use it on a string: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: `[a-z]?` will produce either a string containing one character or a null.  If you used `[a-z]*` you would get an array that you could call join on.  However, if you used `$[a-z]*`, that join would be done for you automatically, yielding a string with zero or more characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error when I was applying `join` function and then returning the result in the same **string array** variable, we cannot do that we should save the result in some other **string type** variable